# how to binding such code in robovm?

Tags: robovm

This is the third library code, how to binding it with java?

```
- (void) setLoginRewardDelegate:(id) delegate loginRewardSelector:(SEL) selector loginRewardPrefix:(NSString*)prefix loginRewardSuffix:(NSString*) suffix;
```

Any information will be appreciated!
thanx.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have already successfully bound your delegate type:

```
@Method(selector = "setLoginRewardDelegate:loginRewardSelector:loginRewardPrefix:loginRewardSuffix:")
public native void setLoginReward (LoginRewardDelegate delegate, Selector selector, String prefix, String suffix);
```

When using your delegate be sure to retain a strong reference to it. Once you no longer need the delegate, remove the strong reference.

```
this.addStrongRef(delegate); // After creating your delegate.
this.removeStrongRef(delegate); // When you no longer need the delegate.
```

Comment: Is it fine to do not remove strong ref to the object at all, if I need it to be alive until termination of the app?